# Select every element of a ul li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu in form of ul li, and I want to a add different css class to every child of the li.

Here is the javascript code:

```
$("#menu").ready(function () {
  $("#menu ul li").addClass("menu_background1");
});
```

css:

```
.menu_background1 {
    background:#FF0;
}

.menu_background2 {
    background:#66C;
}
```

How should I select every child using jQuery? Every child should have different css class..

Comment: You can do so from CSS itself too. Check the [CSS's even and odd](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html) rules.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `addClass`'s function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu ul li").addClass(function(i){
       return 'menu_background' + (i+1)
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Buh9/

Comment: Very nice, didn't realise `addClass()` calculated properties had access to the element index.

Answer (score 0):

use `each` for that

```
$("#menu ul li").each(function(i){
   $(this).addClass("menu_background"+(i+1));
});
```

Comment: every child has different css class, your code add only one class to every child

Answer (score 0):

try with [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector -

```
$("#menu ul li:eq(0)").addClass("menu_background1");
$("#menu ul li:eq(1)").addClass("menu_background2");
```